# Need to Reset the dropdown values On button click

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to reset the dropdown values, on click on Button.

In HTML I have one `onResetClick()` function. In `.ts` file i need to write the logic to reset the dropdwon.

Can Anyone help me with this?

```
    <div class ="space">
    <mat-form-field>
         <mat-label>Is this partner a PEP?</mat-label>
         <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('PepPartner').hasError('required')">
            PEP Partner  is required
          </mat-error>
      <mat-select disableRipple  [(ngModel)]="PepPartner" formControlName="PepPartner">
          <mat-option ></mat-option>
        <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Does this partner blacklisted</mat-label>
      <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('PepBlacklisted').hasError('required')">
          Partner blacklisted is required
        </mat-error>
      <mat-select disableRipple  [(ngModel)]="PepBlacklisted" formControlName="PepBlacklisted" >
        <mat-option ></mat-option>
        <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput placeholder="Blacklist(s)" >
      </mat-form-field>

      <div class="button-position">
          <div class="text-right pr-0 pb-2">
            <div class="btn-group">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button type="button" id="button1" mat-raised-button class="text-uppercase app-btn app-btn-

      primary-border app-color-primary"
                (click)="validateForm()">Save</button>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button type="button" id="button2" mat-raised-button class="text-uppercase app-btn app-btn-

      primary-border app-color-primary"
                (click)="onResetClick()">Clear</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Show your `form` tag html please.

Comment: Are you using reactive form or ngModel binding? Don't use both

Comment: I am Facing this error after clicking on button : Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

this.PepBlacklisted = '';

Comment: After reset the values.. DropDown is in disabled mode... Once I refresh the page, Then only Its working...

Comment: I am Facing this error after clicking on button : Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to decide if you want to use [template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) or [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). Don't use both **together**. In your code, you are using `[(ngModel)]` as well as `formControlName` together.

---

Now, for template driven forms with `ngModel`, you can use try this:

```
onResetClick() {
  PepPartner = '';
  PepBlacklisted = '';
}
```

But if you want to reset the whole form, you can call `reset` on the form in your component. e.g. `this.myForm.reset()`

Comment: After reset the values.. DropDown is in disabled mode... Once I refresh the page, Then only Its working...

Comment: Can you share demo on Stackblitz?

Comment: I am Facing this error after clicking on button : Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.

Comment: Please find the demo link  Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data?file=app%2Fselect-form-example.html

Comment: Updated your stackblitz:
Here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-9fpe7c

Answer (score 0):

First set a value in

```
<mat-option ></mat-option>
```

change it to

```
<mat-option value="0"></mat-option>
```

In case of ngModel simply set the variable value on reset

```
    <mat-select [(value)]="type">
                <mat-option value="all">All</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="online">Online Reg Copy</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="original">Original RC</mat-option>
            </mat-select>

onreset() {
  type="all" 
}
```

If you are using reactive form.You can set value of individual control using

```
this.formName.contols.controlName.setValue("0");
```

Incase you want to reset entire form

```
this.formName.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data?file=app%2Fselect-form-example.html)

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Does this partner blacklisted</mat-label>
      <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('PepBlacklisted').hasError('required')">
          Partner blacklisted is required
        </mat-error>
      <mat-select disableRipple  [(ngModel)]="PepBlacklisted" formControlName="PepBlacklisted" >
        <mat-option ></mat-option>
        <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

.TS

```
onResetClick()
{
 this.PepBlacklisted = undefined;
}
```

Comment: After reset the values.. DropDown is in disabled mode... Once I refresh the page, Then only Its working...

Comment: I am Facing this error after clicking on button : Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.